# some queries regarding updates/inserts rate limits for a database(SQL-based or NoSQL based)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mongodb, amazon-dynamodb

In an app, I need to update a large number of records/insert a large number of records near-simultaneously into a database.

Is there any such insert/update limit which will act as a bottleneck for my app? Is there something I can do to maximise the insert/update rates.

Also, regarding the updates, the same record will not be updated-- many records in one table (clearly identifiable by a key) will be updated-- does this mean that the rate of updates can be significantly higher?

My questions above apply to relational as well as NoSQL databases.

I am now considering using a relational database like SQL Server/MySQL-- however at this stage I am willing to consider noSQL databases like Mongo DB/Dynamo DB as well- my final selection of db depends on which database offers higher insert/update limits.

Comment: Granted, I haven't worked with a NoSQL-style database, but if your sole consideration for choosing one over a 'traditional' RDBMS is 'speed', that's probably the wrong criteria.  From what I understand, NoSQL is generally supposed to handle a different set of problems, usually (especially?) unstructured data.

Comment: @X-Zero i am basically creating a parallel processing framework-- the main task will be to update/insert records as and when parallel tasks are finished/throw up errors/started-- hence the primary considerations for me are simultaneous updates/deletes-- keeping your points in mind, i may even keep the rest of the database (for the parallel processing framework) in a separate database/database type-- but I do need max possible rates of inserts/updates for notifying task commencement/updates/completion...

Comment: depending on how you're managing this, it's not speed you need, but the ability to recover/ACID compliance (which NoSQL-style database tend to have trouble with).  All major modern RDBMSs can have multiple concurrent users.

Answer (score 2):

#### General considerations

The maximum R/W capacity will highly depend on the hardware (HDD vs SSD) and the number of nodes. Also, I believe, it's easier to scale NoSQL for write operations as ACID and consistency are not enforced.

#### For the DynamoDB part of the question

DynamoDB is a **managed service**. You **reserve a given R/W capacity** (the so called 'units') and Amazon scales your database for you. But still, there is a couple of points to take into account :

- Maximum reserved Throughput is 10,000 for Read
- Maximum reserved Throughput is 10,000 for Write

Basically you consume 1 unit per consistent read or write per second and per indivisible kB. (Well, actually, it's even trickier).

BUT, in order to scale, your table is split among **partitions**. So is the reserved Throughput. SO, to reach the maximum possible throughput, you requested Keys needs to be as evenly spread as possible.

These were the database side considerations.

On the **client side**, there are multiple factors to take into account as well:

- TCP/HTTP latency
- maximum open socket at a time

You may use batch_get_item and/or batch_write_items were grouping is possible to reduce the latency impact.

For example, I've never been able to reach the provisioned 1000 write from my office computer, so, you'd better use multiple instances/server to issue your databases request.

#### **TL;DR** (DynamoDB)

- you reserve throughput, Amazon scales to deliver it
- still some gotchas related to the internal implementation
- need to optimize latency
- need to carefully parallelize

I'm not an expert for the other databases types so, I can only guess that the client side considerations will somehow be same, maybe less for MySQL as it uses a binary protocol. Also, you probably will have to manage the databases.

Comment: is the 10,000 reads/writes per second the max rate for a table or for a partition within a table? If it is for a partition, then can i Create/delete partitions programmatically? thanks...

Comment: This limit is per tables. You may get a higher limit if you request Amazon. You have NO control AT ALL on the partitions. You do not even know how many you have. From my tests I know that the minimum is 2, so is it at 1000 throughput.